# ¿Como borrar archivos en memoria que deja el MemoryStream , con C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, manejo-de-memoria

resulta que uso `MemoryStream` para leer un archivo con `ReadToEnd` de la siguiente forma:

```
IEnumerable<uint> uids = Client.Search(SearchCondition.Unseen());
IEnumerable<MailMessage> messages = Client.GetMessages(uids, FetchOptions.Normal);
 foreach (MailMessage msg in messages){

  foreach (Attachment atc in msg.Attachments){
     byte[] allBytes = new byte[msg.Attachments[0].ContentStream.Length];
     int bytesRead = msg.Attachments[0].ContentStream.Read(allBytes, 0, (int)msg.Attachments[0].ContentStream.Length);

     MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream(allBytes);                          
     System.IO.StreamReader archivoXML = new System.IO.StreamReader(memory);
     memory.Close();
     String archivoXML_texto = archivoXML.ReadToEnd();
     archivoXML.Close();
  }

}
```

Debido a esto, tengo la preocupación que en memoria podría quedar varios archivos basuras. Si fuera así, me gustaría saber como borrar o limpiar la memoria de estos archivos despues de leerlos, en donde se van obteniendo con `MemoryStream`.

**Observacion:** leo el adjunto desde un correo usando el protocolo IMAP, y no desde una ruta guardada.

**Observacion 2:** al usar esta instruccion, me lee contenido, sino la tengo, la variable archivoXML_texto almacena vacio:

```
 int bytesRead = msg.Attachments[0].ContentStream.Read(allBytes, 0, (int)msg.Attachments[0].ContentStream.Length);
```

Comment: Con que llames a `Dispose()` bastará....

Comment: ¿Cual es la preocupación exactamente? Porque el Garbage Collector se encarga de recuperar la memoria automáticamente a su debido tiempo.

Comment: También te recomiendo que uses un bloque using al declarar tu MemoryStream. Con esto te garantizas cerrar el flujo de datos y realizar el dispose automáticamente. using(MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream(allBytes) { // resto código }

Comment: Aplica mi comentario anterior también en la declaración de StreamReader. Saludos

Comment: Entonces cuando obtengo el archivo en bye almacenandolo en allBytes  para enviarlo en la variable memory de tipo MemoryStream, no queda archivo basura???. El objetivo era guardar el contenido del archivo en una variable string llamada archivoXML_texto

Comment: Si el archivo es de texto puedes hacer String archivo_texto = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);

Comment: @SergioParra, no puedo hacer la lectura asi como me lo planteas: String archivo_texto = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path); ya que el path, no está en ruta fisica o carpeta, sino que obtengo el adjunto directamente de una lectura de correo usando el protocolo IMAP. Modifique la pregunta detallando mas como hago la lectura del archivo.

Comment: @DanielCorzo como usaria el Dispose, me podrías dar un ejemplo??

Answer (score 1):

C# utiliza el administrado automático de memoria. Esta es realizado por el recolector de basura (Garbage Collector).

Para tu caso no es recomendable utilizar  al recolector de basura pero si aun así decides llamarlo puedes usar los métodos de la clase `System.GC`

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Las clases `MemoryStream` y `StreamReader` implementan la interface `IDisposable` que contienen el método `Dispose` que sirve para liberar recursos y ser elegible por el recolector de basura. Por tanto puedes declararlos en  dentro de un bloque  `using` asegurando que el método `Dispose` se invocara  o  un bloque`try catch finally`

```
byte[] allBytes = new byte[msg.Attachments[0].ContentStream.Length];   

using( MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream(allBytes),
       StreamReader archivoXML = new StreamReader(memory))
{ 
   String archivoXML_texto = archivoXML.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: y porque no sería reconmendable utilizar el recolector de basura???

Comment: @Danilo Por que  estas usando unicamente código administrado.

Comment: entonces, lo mejor seria usar una cosa así???

                            using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream(allBytes)) {                                 
                                StreamReader archivoXML = new StreamReader(memory); 
                                archivoXML_texto = archivoXML.ReadToEnd();
                                archivoXML.Close();
                                memory.Dispose();
                            }

Answer (score 0):

En cuanto a tu pregunta primaria, en `.NET`, generalmente no hay necesidad de preocuparse con recuperar la memoria. `.NET` incluye un recolectador de basura que automáticamente y periódicamente detecta las estructuras en memoria que el programa ya no necesita y los *recolecta*.

Así que, a menos que estás haciendo algo muy avanzado, no te preocupes por recuperar la memoria perdida. Eso se hará de forma automática.

---

Ahora bien, aunque el aspecto de la memoria no es un problema, tu programa definitivamente tiene otros problemas que sí requieren tu atención:

1. Siempre deberías usar las clases `Stream` en bloques `using` para que el `Dispose` se ejecute de forma automática, aún en caso de que se lanze una excepción.
2. A pesar de leer cada attachment en un ciclo, solo estás haciendo referencia al primer attachment con la expresión siguiente (nota el índice `[0]`): `msg.Attachments[0].ContentStream.Length`.
3. *(este punto ya no aplica desde que editastes el código en tu pregunta)* El problema más serio es que ¡nunca lees el contenido de los attachments! Cuando creas el arreglo `allBytes` (`byte[] allBytes = new byte[msg.Attachments[0].ContentStream.Length];`), lo único que estás haciendo es de darle la longitud equivalente al contenido del attachment, pero el contenido en sí son puros ceros.
4. No hay necesidad de usar una arreglo intermediario de bytes. Puedes pasar el `ContentStream` directamente al `StreamReader`.

Con todos estos puntos en mente, el código debería parecerse más bien a lo siguiente:

```
foreach (Attachment atc in msg.Attachments)
{
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(atc.ContentStream))
    {
        String archivoXML_texto = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        // hacer algo con la cadena...
    }
}
```

Comment: Lo intente, pero el valor archivoXML_texto que recibe es vacio.

Comment: Y el código actual que tienes, ¿lo has probado?

Comment: using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream(allBytes)) {                                 
                                StreamReader archivoXML = new StreamReader(memory); 
                                archivoXML_texto = archivoXML.ReadToEnd();
                                archivoXML.Close();
                                memory.Dispose();
                            }

mas lo que comente. Es un problema que no alcanza a leer de esa forma. Algo como el .ContentStream.Read. Edite la pregunta usando esta misma intrucción

Comment: Sospecho que no copiastes bien el código que te puse o le agregastes algo. Porque ese es el patrón correcto y es bien sencillo. Si deseas que trate de entender mejor el problema, incluye en tu pregunta el código exacto que usas que según dices hace que resulte en una cadena vacía.

Comment: Pero ojo, que la pregunta está cambiando de la intención original en cuanto al manejo de la memoria...

Comment: Lo que pasa, es que mi objetivo era leer el adjunto y almacenar su contenido en String, pero como no podía leerlo, tuve que almacenarlo memory, usando el MemoryStream y al usar esto, quería evitar los posibles archivos basuras que quedarían en memoria, por eso llegué a esta pregunta.